# C/C++ Configuration Problem and Execution failed for task ':runtime:buildCMakeDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cmake, ninja

I'm using android studio 2020.3.1, gradle 7.2. I added ninja.exe location to my path and added CMake as well to path. I'm using CMake 3.21.2

when I open the project I get one error:

```
C/C++ Configuration Problem
   appname.runtime | debug | x86
   Compiler exited with error code 1: C:\Users\AmigoUfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe -xc --target=i686-none-linux-android19 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -DUSING_GENERATED_CONFIG_H -D_DEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -ID:/For\ Android\ Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/x86/_deps/sdl2_content-build/include -ID:/For\ Android\ Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/x86/_deps/sdl2_content-src/include -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -idirafter D:/For Android Portierung/ags-mas... (show balloon)
```

and when I try to build APKs I get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':runtime:buildCMakeDebug'.
> Build command failed.
Error while executing process ninja.exe with arguments {-C D:\For Android Portierung\ags-master\Android\library\runtime\.cxx\Debug\1r4n6yv3\armeabi-v7a SDL2 ags engine hidapi pe}
ninja: Entering directory `D:\For Android Portierung\ags-master\Android\library\runtime\.cxx\Debug\1r4n6yv3\armeabi-v7a'
[1/641] Building C object _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_RLEaccel.c.o
FAILED: _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_RLEaccel.c.o
C:\Users\AmigoUfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi19 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -DSDL2_EXPORTS -DUSING_GENERATED_CONFIG_H -D_DEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I"D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-build/include" -I"D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/include" -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -idirafter D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/khronos  -ID:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/hidapi/hidapi  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -fsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wextra -Wendif-labels -Wfloat-equal -Wformat -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-noreturn -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wunused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-cast-align -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-redundant-decls -Werror=write-strings -Wbad-function-cast -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -MD -MT _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_RLEaccel.c.o -MF _deps\sdl2_content-build\CMakeFiles\SDL2.dir\src\video\SDL_RLEaccel.c.o.d -o _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_RLEaccel.c.o -c "D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/SDL_RLEaccel.c"
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Android'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/khronos'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Android'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/hidapi/hidapi'
[2/641] Building C object _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/timer/SDL_timer.c.o
FAILED: _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/timer/SDL_timer.c.o
C:\Users\AmigoUfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi19 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -DSDL2_EXPORTS -DUSING_GENERATED_CONFIG_H -D_DEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I"D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-build/include" -I"D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/include" -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -idirafter D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/khronos  -ID:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/hidapi/hidapi  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -fsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wextra -Wendif-labels -Wfloat-equal -Wformat -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-noreturn -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wunused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-cast-align -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-redundant-decls -Werror=write-strings -Wbad-function-cast -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -MD -MT _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/timer/SDL_timer.c.o -MF _deps\sdl2_content-build\CMakeFiles\SDL2.dir\src\timer\SDL_timer.c.o.d -o _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/timer/SDL_timer.c.o -c "D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/timer/SDL_timer.c"
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Android'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/khronos'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Android'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/hidapi/hidapi'
[3/641] Building C object _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/thread/SDL_thread.c.o
FAILED: _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/thread/SDL_thread.c.o
C:\Users\AmigoUfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi19 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -DSDL2_EXPORTS -DUSING_GENERATED_CONFIG_H -D_DEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I"D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-build/include" -I"D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/include" -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -idirafter D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/khronos  -ID:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/hidapi/hidapi  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -fsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wextra -Wendif-labels -Wfloat-equal -Wformat -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-noreturn -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wunused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-cast-align -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-redundant-decls -Werror=write-strings -Wbad-function-cast -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -MD -MT _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/thread/SDL_thread.c.o -MF _deps\sdl2_content-build\CMakeFiles\SDL2.dir\src\thread\SDL_thread.c.o.d -o _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/thread/SDL_thread.c.o -c "D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/thread/SDL_thread.c"
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Android'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/khronos'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Android'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/hidapi/hidapi'
[4/641] Building C object _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_blit.c.o
FAILED: _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_blit.c.o
C:\Users\AmigoUfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi19 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -DSDL2_EXPORTS -DUSING_GENERATED_CONFIG_H -D_DEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I"D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-build/include" -I"D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/include" -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -idirafter D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/khronos  -ID:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/hidapi/hidapi  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -fsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wextra -Wendif-labels -Wfloat-equal -Wformat -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-noreturn -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wunused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-cast-align -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-redundant-decls -Werror=write-strings -Wbad-function-cast -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -MD -MT _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_blit.c.o -MF _deps\sdl2_content-build\CMakeFiles\SDL2.dir\src\video\SDL_blit.c.o.d -o _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_blit.c.o -c "D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/SDL_blit.c"
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Android'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/khronos'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Android'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/hidapi/hidapi'
[5/641] Building C object _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_blit_0.c.o
FAILED: _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_blit_0.c.o
C:\Users\AmigoUfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi19 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -DSDL2_EXPORTS -DUSING_GENERATED_CONFIG_H -D_DEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I"D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-build/include" -I"D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/include" -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -idirafter D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/khronos  -ID:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/hidapi/hidapi  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -fsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wextra -Wendif-labels -Wfloat-equal -Wformat -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-noreturn -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wunused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-cast-align -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-redundant-decls -Werror=write-strings -Wbad-function-cast -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -MD -MT _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_blit_0.c.o -MF _deps\sdl2_content-build\CMakeFiles\SDL2.dir\src\video\SDL_blit_0.c.o.d -o _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_blit_0.c.o -c "D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/SDL_blit_0.c"
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Android'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/khronos'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Android'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/hidapi/hidapi'
[6/641] Building C object _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_blit_1.c.o
FAILED: _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_blit_1.c.o
C:\Users\AmigoUfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi19 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/AmigoUfo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -DSDL2_EXPORTS -DUSING_GENERATED_CONFIG_H -D_DEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I"D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-build/include" -I"D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/include" -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -idirafter D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/khronos  -ID:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/hidapi/hidapi  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -fsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wextra -Wendif-labels -Wfloat-equal -Wformat -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-noreturn -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wunused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-cast-align -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-redundant-decls -Werror=write-strings -Wbad-function-cast -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -MD -MT _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_blit_1.c.o -MF _deps\sdl2_content-build\CMakeFiles\SDL2.dir\src\video\SDL_blit_1.c.o.d -o _deps/sdl2_content-build/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/video/SDL_blit_1.c.o -c "D:/For Android Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/SDL_blit_1.c"
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Android'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/video/khronos'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Android'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Portierung/ags-master/Android/library/runtime/.cxx/Debug/1r4n6yv3/armeabi-v7a/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/hidapi/hidapi'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I tried refresh linked C++ projects but it didn't help. Does anybody have some solution?

Comment: The error `clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Portierung/ags-master/...` suggests that build tool doesn't work well with the **spaces in the path** (`For Android Portierung`). Try to use directories without spaces in their names.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. thank u.